# Sound Speed in Cosmological Perturbation Theory

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, perturbation-theory

I am following Baumann's notes on Cosmology (available [here](https://cmb.wintherscoming.no/pdfs/baumann.pdf)) and on page 78 the author defines the concept of adiabatic perturbations as having pressure and density fluctuations connected by $\delta P = c_s^2 \delta \rho$, where $c_s$ is identified as the *speed of sound*. What is the justification for naming $c_s$ in this way?

Later, on page 81, it is stated that $c_s = 0$ for linearised CDM (cold dark matter) fluctuations. Can someone provide a mathematical justification for this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the standard definition of the speed of sound as long as you are dealing with adiabatic perturbations. You might want to check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound). On the other hand, for CDM perturbations $c_s=0$ because CDM is collisionless and therefore, pressureless which makes $c_s=0$